# Difference between cordon and taints and toleration (taint-effect- NoExecute)

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes and I was thinking that how cordon works, how it makes the node unschedulable. Does it uses the concept of taints and toleration with the effect of NoExecute, and if not then how cordon is different from taints and tolerations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cordo updates the node object's  `nodes.spec.unschedulable` boolean field to `true`.

The kube-scheduler [treats this as an invisible taint](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/520b991347b9c77635c0e4555f1703a86dcdd4ff/pkg/scheduler/framework/plugins/nodeunschedulable/node_unschedulable.go#L66-L69) `node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule` to the node while considering the node for scheduling pods on it.

Comment: The latter is marked for deprecation: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69010